# I think my if statements got caught up in each other

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm very new to programming in general and Java so excuse my probably easy to solve question. My Part 3 of the code won't show in the output, maybe it has something to do with the if statement at the end of Part 2 as I don't get any error messages in the source code.

I would appreciate the help in case anyone has time to look at it, thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.*;
    public class OddsAndEvens {

        public static void main (String[] args) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            // PART 1 - PICK ODDS OR EVENS
            System.out.println("Let's play a game called \"Odds and Evens\"");
            System.out.print("What is your name? ");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            // Create Strings
            String O = "O";
                    String E = "E";
                    String Odds = "Odds";
                    String Evens = "Evens";
                    // Decision
            System.out.print("Hi " + name + ", which do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens? ");
            String choice = input.next();
            if (choice.equals(O) || choice.equals(Odds)) {
                System.out.println(name + " has picked odds! The computer will be evens.");
            } else if (choice.equals(E) || choice.equals(Evens)) {
                System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! The computer will be odds.");
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

            // PART 2 - PLAY THE GAME
            System.out.print("How many \"fingers\" do you put out? ");
            int userNumber = input.nextInt();
            Random rand = new Random();
            int computerNumber = rand.nextInt(6);
            System.out.println("The computer plays " + computerNumber + " \"fingers\".");
            int sum = userNumber + computerNumber;
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(userNumber + " + " + computerNumber + " = " + sum);
            boolean oddOrEven = sum % 2 == 0;
            if (oddOrEven) {
                System.out.println(sum + " is ...even!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(sum + " is ...odd!");
            }

            // PART 3 - WHO WON?
            if (oddOrEven) {
                while (choice.equals(E)) {
                    System.out.println("That means " + name + " wins! :)");
                }
            } else if (oddOrEven) {
                while (choice.equals(O)) {
                    System.out.println("That means the computer wins!");
                }
            } else if (!oddOrEven) {
                while (choice.equals(E)) {
                    System.out.println("That means the computer wins!");
                }
            } else if (!oddOrEven) {
                while (choice.equals(O)) {
                    System.out.println("That means " + name + " wins! :)");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest removing most of the "while(choice.equals*))" and use

if(oddOrEven && choice.equals(X))

This will make it a bit easier to read. Chances are your choice is never E or O.

Also, your variables start lowercase: "Odds" and "Even" are not good variable names because they start with uppercase.

If you want a more thorough review or assistance in starting out, I would suggest finding yourself a mentor. You can get some for free at https://codingcoach.io/. Those are really nice people willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using else if statements on the same condition two times which will never be reached, since why would it reach the else statement if it was true in the first place?

First one is `else if (oddOrEven)` second one is  `else if (!oddOrEven)`,you should check for your first condition (`oddOrEven` in your case) and inside that check if its equals(E) or not, also replace those while statements with conditional ones.

```
        if (oddOrEven)
        {
            if (choice.equals(E))
            {
                System.out.println("That means " + name + " wins! :)");
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("That means the computer wins!");
            }
        } else
        {
            if (choice.equals(E))
            {
                System.out.println("That means the computer wins!");
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("That means " + name + " wins! :)");
            }
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        }
```